# How should I stop my table from leaving white space in the bottom of it?

Tags: html, css

For some reason there is a little piece of blank space in the last part of my table... [Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLRky.png)

I have tried fixing it by using valign and such on the table but nothing is working. Here is the code:

```
<table width="135" align="right" style="border-collapse:collapse;border:4px solid #9f0606;">
  <tr>
    <td style="border-collapse:collapse;border:4px solid #9f0606;">
      <form id="chatform" name="chatform" method="post">
        <textarea name="chat" cols="13" rows="1"></textarea>
        <input name="Send" type="submit" value="Send" />
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What's around that table?

Comment: Try adding "margin: 0" to style.

Comment: Your provided code works fine in firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/2JEvu/  Do you have a specific browser that this fails in?  Probably some other style causing the space.

Comment: Around the table is basically a ton of other code that just does stuff like list user stats and stuff.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't exhibit any issues. Please post a complete example including any other CSS or HTML that might be causing this.

Comment: I am viewing it in Chrome

Comment: If theres whitespace between </table> and the next node, some browsers display minimal gaps between blocks.

Comment: Margin doesn't work either... Hold on a minute I'll look to see if there is any other code I need to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about setting `padding:0` on your `td` cells?

Or simply: `td,form,textarea,input {padding: 0;margin: 0;}`

Comment: Didn't do anything :(

Comment: Works! Just had to put on my form, textarea, and input too